# Matching Firebase UI Database to Firebase Auth/DB/storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

So I'm working on my first Android app through Android Studio and I'm using a year old guide. My project is connected to Firebase and I can't seem to match between the correct versions.

my current firebase implementations in the build.gradle are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.3'
```

i must add the following implementation as well:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
```

I know for a fact that if I change the Firebase version to `11.8.0` it will sync properly with Firebase UI DB version 3.2.2 but it will damage other parts of the app so it's not an option for me. How can I know what UI DB version matches the firebase versions I listed?

Answer (score 1):

Try versions mentioned in [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/6.2.0)

```
Dependency         |    Version
firebase-core      |    19.2.0
firebase-auth      |    17.2.1
firebase-database  |    19.2.0
firebase-firestore |    21.3.1
firebase-storage   |    19.1.0
play-services-auth |    17.0.0
```

Comment: Won't compile, 
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.2.0.
any ideas? thank you for the reply

Comment: Did you add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` to project gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to add the right version:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases